# count or having count

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have a table that has an id using the given query

```
select id_client as id1
from client
group by id_client having count(*) = 2
```

I get all id's that have duplicates.I want to receive the following in one request

```
select count(*) as All,
(select count(id_client) from client )as id1,
(select count(id_client) from client )as id2,
(select count(id_client) from client )as id3
from client

All  id1   id2   id3
100   50    30    20
```

Comment: You have three identical subqueries.  And I think the expectation that they return different numbers.  That is not reasonable.

Comment: I gave an example, it can be done without requests, how can a similar request be made?

Comment: . . Your question should clearly explain what you want.  I can speculate (and in fact did speculate), but the question could be much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want the counts of the number of times that ids appear.  For this, use aggregation . . . twice:

```
select count(*) as total,
       count(*) filter (where cnt = 1) as onesies,
       count(*) filter (where cnt = 2) as twosies,
       count(*) filter (where cnt = 3) as threesies
from (select id_client, count(*) as cnt
      from clients c
      group by id_client
     ) c;
```